# Is EKCalendarItem's UUID truly unique?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ekeventkit

The class EKEvent in iOS 4 has a property called eventIdentifier, which is not "truly" unique (it mostly when local calendar syncs with remote calendar).

In iOS 5 sdk, EKCalendarItem has a property called UUID which according to the documentation is unique

My question is, has anyone find out this is not true?  I trying to write some synchronization code with my core data and the local calendar and I "NEED" a unique identifier for it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of UUIDs (Universally unique identifiers) the word unique means "practically unique" rather than "guaranteed unique".

According to the section [Random UUID probability of duplicates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) in the article [Universally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) of Wikipedia, after generating 68,719,476,736 UUIDs, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be 0.0000000000000004.

Answer (score 2):

No, UUID are different for same event on different devices. Checked.